# Magento 2 : Show Icons for Each Category in Mega Menu

Tags: magento2, category, menu, favicons

Is there a way to check If category has image? I want to show icons for each category individual in Mega Menu.

I want to dynamic add categories in mega menu. 
Please see attached screenshot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in Category page by using below code.

```
$_category  = $block->getCurrentCategory(); // get Current Category
$_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()
```

If $_ImgUrl is not equal to blank means category has image else not.

Thanks

Comment: How to show icons for each category?

Comment: You have to create image file upload control in category.

Comment: I have create the image for each category, but I not getting the image URL yet. I am using the below extension for display the categories on the home page.

https://github.com/ibnab/magento2-home-categories